# My photos aren't being saved

Tags: android, eclipse, image, save

I'm trying to make an app which basically takes pictures and saves them in a folder which I've already created, but when I check the folder, it's empty. Is there a way I could check if my files are actually being saved?
Here's my code:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    filePathTop = "/TopClothes/Image_" + timeStamp + ".jpg" ;
    //filePathBot = "/BottomClothes/Image_" + timeStamp + ".png" ;

    File foldertop = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TopClothes");
    File folderbot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/BottomClothes");

    File image = new File(foldertop, "Image_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
    boolean success = true;

    if (!foldertop.exists()) {
        success = foldertop.mkdir();
    }
```

And then:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bCamera:

        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);


    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission to the manifest?

Comment: @kevinkl3 yes, I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.bCamera:

    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
break;
}
```

}

try to put image uri before starting activity

Comment: Omg, I can't believe that was the error! Thank you very much!